# Indexing with a Date field (as a String) in ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, date, sorting, indexing, dataset

on Delphi XE2,
I have a ClientDataSet which have many fields as Name, ...
It have a field named Date, as value type String. Containing a Date (dd/mm/yyyy)
I want to print content of ClientDataSet, using FastReport.
I want before to sort content ascending according to the Date field. I'm using index.
But when doing this, sorting does only sorts fields according to the content of the Date string before the "/".
form example dates like : 12/11/2012, 15/10/2012, 01/12/2012 are sorting like this : 01/12/2012 - 12/11/2012 - 15/10/2012.
ny idea how doing this correctly ?!

Comment: That's why you should not have dates in string fields unless they are formatted as yyyymmdd (hhmmss). You could add a calculated field that calculates the date from the string (using StrToDate or some such function) and sort on that calculated field.

Answer (score 3):

The sorting is correct! As you have a string field, the sorting is made like strings are sorted i.e. from left to right. If you want it sorted by Date you need either a date field or sort the string representation like yyyy/mm/dd.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

- Bring the field as a DateTime field. You would have to change the original SQL to that.
- Do what Marjan suggested, bringing that string field formatted on an ISO-like style (which allows for the field to be ordered cronologically when string sorting is aplied) and creating an calculated field for user-display formatting.
- Creating a new field on the `TDatasetProvider`'s OnGetRecords event and populating it as a Date field.
- Similar as above but creating a string field with the date formatted in ISO-Like style.

I personally suggest the first approach if possible.